# Angular, Show Success alert after rooter navigate

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to find a way to do a popup message or an alert after i successfully fill my form and redirect to another page in Angular

Something like "New Form is successfully added" after navigation

This is my code for the for the rooter navigate

```
specialEvents = []

  constructor(    private _eventService: EventService,
    private _router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._eventService.getSpecialEvents()
      .subscribe(
        res => this.specialEvents = res,
        err => {
          if( err instanceof HttpErrorResponse ) {
            if (err.status === 401) {
              this._router.navigate(['/home'])
            }
          }
        }
      )
  }
```

Can anyone please give me an idea how to show a popup or a success alert after **this._router.navigate(['/home'])**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the alert popup event in the **ngOnInit** method of the component which is linked to the route "/home".

For Example:
If HomeComponent is linked to the path "/home" in your app router as

{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }

then the component "HomeComponent" will be initiated during router navigation to "/home". Hence in the **ngOnInit** method of the "HomeComponent" add your alert popup function to show the alert message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can setTimeout:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._eventService.getSpecialEvents()
      .subscribe(
        res => this.specialEvents = res,
        err => {
          if( err instanceof HttpErrorResponse ) {
            if (err.status === 401) {
              this._router.navigate(['/home'])

        setTimeout(() => {
          window.alert('Unauthorized');
          }, 500);
            }

          }
        }
      )
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of choices there.

1. You can use an optimistic approach call your toast or alert after the `navigation`:

```
this._router.navigate(['/home']);
alert('Navigated');
```

2. You can subscribe to router events and when navigation starts from your component and the ends on your home component you can throw your alert there.

In your `app.component` you can add this:

```
this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
 if (event.url.inlcudes('home')) alert();
});
```

3. You can use router's navigation promise chain to handle the navigation in your component:

```
this.router.navigate(['/', 'home'])
    .then(nav => {
       window.alert('Home');
    }, err => {
      console.log(err) // when there's an error
    });
```

PS: If you wonder, how to create a custom toaster? I would suggest you to use to use a 3rd party library as a start. [ngx-toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr) is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your app.ts  file file add this

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {

     setTimeout(() => {
       if (this.router.url === '/home') {
         window.alert('welcome');
       }
     },1000)
  }
```